# how do i query woocommerce booking post type on init action

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-bookings

I am trying to export `wc_booking` booking details based on  start date on form submit. But the problem is that i cannot get those posts on init action. So is there any other way to query for woocommerce booking post type.

And moreover I am tryin to export these datas on csv. So is ther any possible way to do it.